# Does the number of methods in a class definition affect the memory consumption when instantiating the class?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management

I would like to know the answer to this question. To give some context:

I am currently writing my own chess engine in Java (yes I know C++ would be faster), I need to generate lots and lots of e.g MoveOrder objects representing a path from one boardstate to another. It is convenient for me to have a fair few instance methods in the class definition, will that affect the speed of the program when there are huge numbers of these objects? I.e should I instead make some kind of Utility class containing static methods which handle the same functionality?

Comment: When you say "huge numbers of these objects", what do you mean by that? Hundreds? Thousands? Hundred of thousands?

Comment: Hundreds of thousands I think, maybe millions.

Comment: No, it won't. Methods belong to the class, not to instances of the class. Have you counted the number of methods in String or Integer? Every program use a lot of those.

Answer (score 1):

The count of methods has no influence on the memory consumption of a single object. Each object only contains a header, including the address to its class, and the fields, not all of the class methods.

Answer (score 0):

It's the total size used by the instance variables, not the number of methods that affect the space taken up by an instance of a class.

Answer (score 0):

No. The method exists only once. In C++ you might have heard about the method table. It's not called the methods per object table. Doing it in a different way would be a waste of memory, because once compiled, a method does not change any more.

If you read about [a Method (Oracle)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html), it says (emphasis mine):

> provides information about, and access to, a single method on a **class or interface**.

as opposed to

"provides information about, and access to, a single method on a **object**."

However, many objects will allocate memory and memory may be swapped to disk if there's not enough RAM, so the number of objects will affect the performance, but it's not due to the methods.